# In R why is na.action = na.omit in t.test() not working?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to loop through a list of columns in data.table and run t-tests on each. I know I have records with missing data so I added '''na.action = na.omit''' but I am still getting an error.

Here's a sample

| A | B | C | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | 1 | 1 |
| NA | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 1 |

```
sapply(c("A","B","C"), function(x){
        d[, t.test(x~Y, na.action = na.omit)]
                })
```

And I'm getting back this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = x ~ Y, na.action = na.omit) : variable lengths differ (found for 'Y')
```

Comment: `na.omit` removes the entire row.  So, with 'A', you get only single observation

Comment: Also `x ~ Y`, you may need to create a formula with paste or reformulate i.e. `d[, lapply(c('A', 'B', 'C'), function(nm) list(t.test(reformulate(nm, response = 'Y'), na.action = na.omit, data = .SD)))]`

Comment: To clarify, this is a subset of a larger dataset to the actual dataset. I have a few hundred records. Also, t.test(A~Y) is not the same as  t.test(A,Y). Finally, the solution proposed didn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `reformulate('A', response = 'Y')`

Comment: I never said to use `t.test(A, Y)`  there is a `reformulate` inside it.  May be you omitted that part

Comment: My assumption is that my failure had to do with data.table syntax, but that's not the case. Here's what I did: '```for (i in list(outcome_items)) {
  x = d[,c(i)]
  y = d$treat
  result[i] = list(t.test(reformulate(x,response = y), na.action = na.omit))$p.value
}```

Comment: Here is the error. Error in t.test.formula(reformulate(x, response = y), na.action = na.omit) : 'formula' missing or incorrect

Comment: I was using the `y` as the column  names.  What is `d$treat`

Comment: y = d$treat. This is my actual variable name. Given the example I've posted here that's the same as y = d$Y.  I didn't catch that in my edits in Stack. They're correct in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I continued to see the same issue for t.test, but I was able to use a simple lm and lapply to make this work.

```
dt_long <- (dt %>% dplyr::select(item_a, item_b, item_c, treat, block, covariate_x) %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols = -c(block, treat, covariate_x))
        )

#keep the order of items; otherwise r alpha sorts
list_of_outcomes <- split(d_long, forcats::fct_inorder(factor(dt_long$name)), lex.order = FALSE)
models_1 <- lapply(list_outcomes, function(x) lm(value ~ treat + block + covariate_x, x)) # consider interacting with block
```

Nice thing about models_1 is that in this form, stargazer can output a clean table, and you can get a list of robust standard errors easily.